# How to export large Neo4j datasets for analysis in an automated fashion

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, cypher, bigdata

I've run into a technical challenge around Neo4j usage that has had me stumped for a while. My organization uses Neo4j to model customer interaction patterns. The graph has grown to a size of around 2 million nodes and 7 million edges. All nodes and edges have between 5 and 10 metadata properties. Every day, we export data on all of our customers from Neo4j to a series of python processes that perform business logic.

Our original method of data export was to use paginated cypher queries to pull the data we needed. For each customer node, the cypher queries had to collect many types of surrounding nodes and edges so that the business logic could be performed with the necessary context. Unfortunately, as the size and density of the data grew, these paginated queries began to take too long to be practical.

Our current approach uses a custom Neo4j procedure to iterate over nodes, collect the necessary surrounding nodes and edges, serialize the data, and place it on a Kafka queue for downstream consumption. This method worked for some time but is now taking long enough so that it is also becoming impractical, especially considering that we expect the graph to grow an order of magnitude in size.

I have tried the [cypher-for-apache-spark](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark) and [neo4j-spark-connector](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) projects, neither of which have been able to provide the query and data transfer speeds that we need.

We currently run on a single Neo4j instance with 32GB memory and 8 cores. Would a cluster help mitigate this issue?

Does anyone have any ideas or tips for how to perform this kind of data export? Any insight into the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is export really necessary? Have you tried using a neo4j Python driver (like the [official Bolt driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/)) to perform your business logic directly on the neo4j DB?

Comment: Unfortunately the logic is beyond what cypher can offer. We have trained classifiers and models that need access to the data.

Comment: Very little of the business logic needs to be performed in Cypher. You could just use the driver to get the data needed by the business logic written in pure Python.

Comment: The data that we need more or less involves all of the data in the DB. And each query has significant data overlap with each other, making individual queries far less efficient than a data export and application logic that manipulates it. External document caching could probably help quite a bit, but we need to re-build and re-process the whole DB frequently.

Comment: I'm not a Neo4j expert so take the question with a grain of salt but if your application requires paging through in the database (and you can do the logic using cypher queries) it may be worth it to consider other storage methods? Do you know if this is outside of the interaction pattern Neo4j was built for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember Neo4j doesn't support horizontal scaling and all data is stored in a single node. To use Spark you could try to store your graph in 2+ nodes and load the parts of the dataset from these separate nodes to "simulate" the parallelization. I don't know if it's supported in both of connectors you quote.

But as told in the comments of your question, maybe you could try an alternative approach. An idea:

1. Find a data structure representing everything you need to train your model.
2. Store such "flattened" graph in some key-value store (Redis, Cassandra, DynamoDB...)
3. Now if something changes in the graph, push the message to your Kafka topic
4. Add consumers updating the data in the graph and in your key-value store directly after (= make just an update of the graph branch impacted by the change, no need to export the whole graph or change the key-value store at the same moment but it would very probably lead to duplicate the logic)
5. Make your model querying directly the key-value store.

It depends also on how often your data changes, how deep and breadth is your graph ?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up pushing a flattened document to elasticsearch in a neo4j trigger whenever a relevant node was updated

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j Enterprise supports clustering, you could use the Causal Cluster feature and launch as many read replicas as needed, run the queries in parallel on the read replicas, see this link: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/setup-new-cluster/#causal-clustering-add-read-replica